# How to create generic class extending React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm using [Flow.js](https://flow.org/) in my React application.

Within it I've created custom `Form` component extending `React.Component`:

```
import * as React from 'react'

class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, FormState> {
  // utils for form-handling logic in my form components
}
```

Here are my form types:

```
export type ValidationResult = Array<string>
export type Validator = (value: any) => string | false

export type CompositeValidationResult = { [string]: ValidationResult };

export type FormData = { [string]: any };
export type FormErrors = { [string]: ValidationResult };
export type FormValidators = { [string]: Array<Validator> };

export type FormSetErrors = (FormErrors) => void
export type FormSetSubmitting = (boolean) => void
export type FormOnClean = (FormData, FormValidators, FormSetErrors) => FormData | false
export type FormOnSubmit = (FormData, FormSetSubmitting, FormSetErrors) => void

export type FormProps = {
  initialData: FormData,
  validators?: FormValidators,
  onClean: FormOnClean,
  onSubmit: FormOnSubmit
}

export type FormState = {
  isSubmitting: boolean,
  data: FormData,
  errors: FormErrors
}
```

So far so good!

Now, I'm trying to inherit from my Form in another component, `SignInForm`. This form differs from `Form` in a way that it expects one more property, `onHide` property. Just using this prop in my component gives me following error:

```
Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:20
 20:     const { onHide } = this.props
                 ^^^^^^ property `onHide`. Property not found in
 20:     const { onHide } = this.props
                            ^^^^^^^^^^ FormProps
```

Ok, works as intended, now lets create custom type for extended props:

```
type Props = {
  onHide: () => void
}

class SignInForm extends Form {
  props: FormProps & Props

  // some SignInForm specific stuff
}
```

But this produces following error:

```
 10: class SignInForm extends Form {
           ^^^^^^^^^^ SignInForm. Cannot extend
 10: class SignInForm extends Form {
                              ^^^^ Form
  Property `props` is incompatible:
      6: class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, FormState> {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^ FormProps. This type is incompatible with. See: js/components/Form/Form.js:6
     11:   props: FormProps & Props
                              ^^^^^ Props
      Property `onHide` is incompatible:
         11:   props: FormProps & Props
                                  ^^^^^ property `onHide`. Property not found in
          6: class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, FormState> {
                                                ^^^^^^^^^ FormProps. See: js/components/Form/Form.js:6
```

I've also tried going other way:

```
type Props = {
  onHide: () => void
}

class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
  // ...
}
```

But this results in longer error:

```
Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:10
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
           ^^^^^^^^^^ SignInForm. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:10
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:10
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ variance check: `Form`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:12
 12:     this.onChange('username', ev.currentTarget.value)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `onChange`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:16
 16:     this.onChange('password', ev.currentTarget.value)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `onChange`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:20
 20:     const { onHide } = this.props
                            ^^^^^^^^^^ property `props`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:21
 21:     const { data, errors, isSubmitting } = this.state
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^ property `state`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`

Error: js/containers/SignInForm/SignInForm.js:25
 25:         <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `onSubmit`. Expected polymorphic type instead of
 10: class SignInForm extends Form<FormProps & Props, FormState> {
                              ^^^^ statics of `Form`
```

From this I'm understanding that while `React.Component` may be generic type, `Form` is not, but I've no idea how to carry on from here. I've been wondering if its possible to suggest compatible types via:

```
class Form extends React.Component<P:FormProps, S:FormState>
```

But this is syntax error.

So I'm at loss here, looking for a solution, but my searches so far turned up nothing.

Comment: Try to look at `inheritance inversion` and `HOC (High Order Components)`. This link for me is useful: https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Comment: @TentenPonce yes, I am aware of those patterns, but the question is explicitly about inheritance and Flow.js. Still, thank you.